# Android subtracting Date

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, subtraction

So I am trying to subtract 2 dates I have come up with this code :

```
java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss_yyyy.MM.dd");
java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date();
java.util.Date date2 = df.parse("00:00:00_2013.01.01");
long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

But the problem is the **diff** isn't correct.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: why you are concerting them into date and then subtracing ? simply subtract long values and then convert the result into datetime :)

Comment: the question is what should `diff` represent? The difference in days? Weeks? Years? Minutes? @Lucifer your solution would deliver crazy results. Subtracting yesterday from today would result in 02.01.1970 which means what to you?

Comment: I have the actual date "new Date()" and the end date.

Comment: i have calced an i get : diff/1000 = 1940867 / 60 / 60 /24/ = 22,..... and 22 days is not true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your diff sample in the comment is wrong. I tried your code and got this result:

```
try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss_yyyy.MM.dd");
    Date date1 = new java.util.Date();
    Date date2 = df.parse("00:00:00_2013.01.01");
    long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    Log.e("TEST" , date1.getTime() + " - " + date2.getTime() + " - " + diff);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("TEST", "Exception", e);
}

date1: 1350921506492
date2: 1356994800000
diff: 6073293508

diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 = 70,292748935
```

And roughly checked 70 days until new year sounds solid.

Comment: Why is java date classes so horrible? C# DateTime is substantially easier to work with.

Comment: @Zapnologica The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java were the industry's first serious attempt at taking on the very thorny problem of handling date-time, a problem ignored for decades. Those classes were based on work done at IBM and Taligent. But you are correct, ultimately they fail, with flaws in both design and implementation. The solution is the open-source Joda-Time library or the new java.time package built into Java 8 and later (inspired by Joda-Time).

Answer (score 3):

## Hope this will help

#### The code below output time if the date difference is less than a day, out day when the date difference is less then 7 days and so on....

```
public String ConvertDateToReadableDate(String DateTime) {
    if (DateTime != null) {
        if (!DateTime.equals("")) {
            // the input should be in this format 2019-03-08 15:14:29 
            //if not you have to change the pattern in SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
            
                Date newDate;
                Date currentDate = new java.util.Date();
                int hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
                String dayName = "", dayNum = "", monthName = "", year = "";
                long numOfMilliSecondPassed = 0;
                float milliSecond = 86400000.0f; // 1 day is 86400000 milliseconds 
                float numOfDayPass;

                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

                try {
                    newDate = dateFormat.parse(DateTime); // convert String to date
                    numOfMilliSecondPassed = currentDate.getTime() - newDate.getTime(); //get the difference in date in millisecond

                    hour = Integer.parseInt((String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("hh", newDate));
                    min = Integer.parseInt((String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("mm", newDate));
                    sec = Integer.parseInt((String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("ss", newDate));
                    dayName = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", newDate);
                    dayNum = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", newDate);
                    monthName = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", newDate);
                    year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", newDate);


                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Convert the milliseconds to days
                numOfDayPass = (numOfMilliSecondPassed / milliSecond);       


                if (numOfDayPass < 1) {
                    return hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                } else if ((numOfDayPass >= 1) && (numOfDayPass < 7)) {
                    return dayName + " "+ hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                } else if ((numOfDayPass >= 7) && (numOfDayPass < 30)) {
                    int weeks = (int) numOfDayPass / 7;

                    if(weeks > 1) {
                        return weeks + " weeks ago";
                    }else{
                        return weeks + " week ago";
                    }
                }else if((numOfDayPass >= 30) && (numOfDayPass < 90) ){
                    int months = (int) numOfDayPass/30;

                    if(months > 1) {
                        return months + " months ago";
                    }else{
                        return months + " month ago";
                    }
                }else if((numOfDayPass >= 360) && (numOfDayPass < 1080) ){
                    int years = (int) numOfDayPass/360;

                    if(years > 1) {
                        return years + " years ago";
                    }else{
                        return years + " year ago";
                    }
                }else{
                    return dayName + " " + dayNum + " " + monthName + " " + year + " "+
                    hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                }

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```